# CMock - Multiple definitions

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmake, header-files, cmock

I am starting to work in test driven C development.

I used CMock to generate my mock classes by running commands like:

```
ruby cmock.rb ../../../src/util.h
```

My current package structure is:

```
app/root
  | bin
      | *.*
  | build
      | *.*
  |- cmake
     |- modules
        |- CodeCoverage.cmake
  |- coverage
      |- *.*
  |- external
      |- Unity
      |- CMock
      |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- src
      |- *.c
      |- *.h
      |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- mocks
      |- *.c
      |- *.h
      |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- tests
      |- *.c
      |- *.h
      |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- CMakeLists.txt
```

I have the CMakeLists.txt setup to compile src as a library:

```
add_library(app SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Tests is setup to compile as an executable:

```
add_executable(tests ${TEST_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(tests app Unity mocks)
```

And mocks is setup to compile as a library:

```
add_library(mocks ${MOCK_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(mocks app Unity CMock)
```

I've tried multiple locations for the mock headers and have been playing around, but I'm missing a fundamental of how to not get a **multiple definitions** error.

Can anyone lend some guidance on what is incorrect about my file structure or strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer here: https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CMock/issues/97

Basically, it all comes down to linking just the files that you need for each test. When using Unity, every test becomes its own Executable.